# Duplicate list values and add in new column to dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I could not find a similar question.

I have a toy dataframe:

```
      A     B    participant
0     1     3    1
1     2     4    1
2     5     8    2
3     4     9    2
```

I have a list that corresponds to a *single* measurement made for each participant.

```
measurement_list = [2.5, 4.7]
```

How can I assign each participant's measurement to a new column? Desired:

```
      A     B    participant    measurement
0     1     3    1              2.5
1     2     4    1              2.5
2     5     8    2              4.7
3     4     9    2              4.7
```

(The real dataset is much, much larger.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `np.repeat`

```
#if it is unsorted dataframe , using sort_values 1st 
#df=df.sort_values('participant') 
df.assign(measurement=np.repeat(measurement_list,df.participant.value_counts(sort=False)))

Out[324]: 
   A  B  participant  measurement
0  1  3            1          2.5
1  2  4            1          2.5
2  5  8            2          4.7
3  4  9            2          4.7
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you! I was surprised that I had to redefine my dataframe, however.

Comment: @MeC yw ~ ;-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in 2 steps.

```
d = dict(enumerate(measurement_list, 1))

df['measurement'] = df['participant'].map(d)
```

**Result**

```
   A  B  participant  measurement
0  1  3            1          2.5
1  2  4            1          2.5
2  5  8            2          4.7
3  4  9            2          4.7
```

**Explanation**

- Create a dictionary mapping via `enumerate`, using optional start counter of 1.
- Use `pd.Series.map` to map participant to measurement via the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that there is a one-to-one relationship between participant and position in the `measurement_list`.  I take advantage of Numpy array slicing.  This should be very fast.

```
measurement_list = np.array([2.5, 4.7])
df.assign(measurement=measurement_list[df.participant.values - 1])

   A  B  participant  measurement
0  1  3            1          2.5
1  2  4            1          2.5
2  5  8            2          4.7
3  4  9            2          4.7
```

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a great candidate for [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Given your setup code:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
   ...: (1, 3, 1),
   ...: (2, 4, 1),
   ...: (5, 8, 2),
   ...: (4, 9, 2)], columns=['A', 'B', 'participant'])

In [3]: measurement_list = [2.5, 4.7]
```

You can easily build a second dataframe mapping a new column to the values at the corresponding indices in your measurement list as follows:

```
In [4]: df_with_measures = df1.assign(measurement=lambda x: x.participant.apply(lambda y: measurement_list[y - 1]))

In [5]: df_with_measures
Out[5]: 
   A  B  participant  measurement
0  1  3            1          2.5
1  2  4            1          2.5
2  5  8            2          4.7
3  4  9            2          4.7
```

This takes the existing dataframe, `df1`, and assigns a new column by applying the provided function to the entire existing dataframe. The lambda that I used takes the provided dataframe and applies a simple mapping to the existing participants column (using [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html))

Take care to watch for the one-based identifiers of your participants against the zero-based indices in your measurement list.